# Invalid parent id

Tags: jtable

We get "Invalid parent id" when saving our custom JTable (`$ourTable->store(); $ourTable->getErrors();`). We didn't have this problem before 3.7.3. Is this commit related? https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/14319/files

Any tips welcomed. This is a critical issue for our site.

Edit: Problem caused by Falang. They override the database driver, and their driver cannot handle `->select('1')`, it seems. I've notified the Falang devs about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to a change in Joomla 3.7.3 and the select (1) query not compatible with Falang due to a bug in MySQL-php.
You have to update your php version to php 7+ or use the fix in the Joomla pull request here
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/17003/